# VBA code inexplicably changing columns in formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace existing excel links with a new filename, then filter a column and copy and paste a selection in another workbook. Everything seems to work as intended, but the column I'm replacing the links in and filtering, has its column references changing from I to H and A to B.

The formula is `=IFERROR(INDEX('[File.xlsx]Macro'!$I:$I,MATCH(A2,'[File.xlsx]Macro'!$A:$A,0)),"")`

It turns into `=IFERROR(INDEX('[File.xlsx]Macro'!$H:$H,MATCH(A2,'[File.xlsx]Macro'!$B:$B,0)),"")`

The end result is incorrect as you can imagine. Here is the code:

```
Sub IndexMissingBudget()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim varFileName As Variant
Dim arrLinks As Variant
Dim MyLink As String
Dim I As Long
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open "S:\AddBack.xlsx"
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb2.Sheets("AddBack")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Macro")
    
    'Check for links
    arrLinks = wb2.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    If IsEmpty(arrLinks) Then
        MsgBox "This workbook does not contain any links!", vbOKOnly, "No External Links"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Get new source file
    varFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select a File to Import")
    If varFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    
    'Add braces [] around file name
    MyLink = Mid(varFileName, InStrRev(varFileName, "\") + 1)
    varFileName = Replace(varFileName, MyLink, "[" & MyLink & "]")

    'Change link source
    arrLinks = wb2.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    
    For I = 1 To UBound(arrLinks)
    
    'Add braces [] around each link filename
    MyLink = Mid(arrLinks(I), InStrRev(arrLinks(I), "\") + 1)
    MyLink = Replace(arrLinks(I), MyLink, "[" & MyLink & "]")

    'Replace old LinkSources file name with new
    If Not ws1.Cells.Find(MyLink, , xlFormulas) Is Nothing Then
        ws1.Cells.Replace What:=MyLink, Replacement:=varFileName, LookAt:=xlPart
    End If
    
    Next I
    
    'Filter and Copy Paste
    ws1.Range("A:O").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=" & ""
    ws1.Range("G2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range("G2:O2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate
    ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

End Sub

Thank you

Comment: Did you try executing step by step with F8 to see the exact moment where this happens?

Comment: In the new workbook/worksheet where you paste the data, do you paste it to the same range? If you copy `G2:O30` in the first worksheet, do you paste it to `G2:O30` in the new one, or do you paste it to `F2:N30`, i.e. offset the range?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your pasting it to the different Column. Example your copying from Column A:B but your pasting it to Column B:C. Even if it has a $ sign sometimes Copying to another Workbook will change the Range.